# Write to CSV in Rails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, logging, heroku

I would like to write some user-generated data to a CSV file in production in Rails, but I have been unable to successfully write and obtain the data. It is possible that it is not being written, or that my method of trying to obtain it is flawed (or both).

This is in my static pages controller:

```
def home
  line = ["static_pages","home","test"]
  CSV.open("db/output.csv", "ab") do |csv|
    csv << line
  end
  ...
end
```

I've tried two ways of viewing the production version of the `output.csv` file, both with the same result.

Method #1:

```
$ heroku run console
> Dir.chdir("db")
> puts CSV.open("output.csv").read()
```

Method #2

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout FETCH_HEAD -- db/output.csv
```

Both methods return the version of the file that was most recently updated while in the development environment.

I could easily be missing something fundamental here. Please let me know what you think may be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on Heroku filesystem. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem .
Consider it as "read-only" and try to use another method to store data (database for instance).

Comment: Thank you. I received this advice from a friend on FB who explained that I had nothing to gain by not using the database, that there is plenty of memory available and that my app directory is not a reliable place to store data. I have created a simply Activity model that will do the trick.